# How to stop tokbox screen sharing in SWIFT

Tags: swift, opentok

I am working on an IOS application(SWIFT) in which i have used tokbox for screensharing, i am able to share the screen but not able to stop screensharing.

This is the code I have used for screensharing.

```
 publisher?.videoType = .screen
 publisher?.audioFallbackEnabled = false
 let cap = ScreenCapturer(withView:view)
 publisher?.videoCapture = cap
 session?.publish(publisher, error: &error)
```

Can anyone guide to stop screensharing in swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop screen sharing will need to stop the publisher from streaming. To do that you can call:

`[OTSession unpublish:error:]`

More info is available on the [Video API guides](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/ios/#stop_publishing)

For your case, where you are adding screen sharing to an existing call, you will need to create an additional publisher for the screen sharing rather than editing the existing one. To use the existing publisher it will require the publisher to be reinitialised to switch between publishing a camera feed vs a screen which will stop publishing audio too.

In addition to creating a new publisher, you need to create a new subscriber for the other user, you can do that in the `subscriberDidConnect` delegate function on the `OTSubscriberDelegate`.

Additionally, you will need to handle the destruction of both the new publisher and subscriber. This will be done in the delegate functions are you using already on the `OTSessionDelegate` and `OTPublisherDelegate`.

I have created a [demo app](https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo) which demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: Hi, Already we tried to stop the publisher but he is coming out of the session but as per our requirement he should be in call but we need to stop screen sharing and turn on camera to continue video call.

Comment: In that case, you can try toggling the `publishVideo` property on your publisher.

Comment: Hi, We have tried to set publishVideo Property of publisher, but not able to stop sharing. This is the code we tried.
 publisher.videoCapture?.releaseCapture()
 let capturer = ScreenCapturer(withView:view)
 publisher.videoCapture = capturer
 capturer.stop()
 publisher.videoType = .camera
 publisher.audioFallbackEnabled = false
 publisher.publishVideo = true
If possible can you give code to stop screensharing?

Comment: Are you using the same publisher for video and screen sharing or a separate screen sharing publisher?

Comment: We are using same publisher for both video and screen sharing.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the Demo App. 
We tried to run the demo app which you have shared, but screensharing is not working in that app. When we click on 'Share Screen' button, we get "Publisher failed: Timed out while attempting to publish."  and the subscriber is still seeing publishers's video only not his screen/view. 
When we tried with single publisher, we were able to share screen but facing issue in stop sharing, but if we use two publishers we are not able to share screen.

Comment: Are you running it in the simulator or on device? Try running it between two simulators. Which version of OpenTok too

Comment: We tried running between device and simulator, that time it was not working. Now we tried with two simulators its working now. Thank you. We are facing one more issue, in our app we are sharing one new ViewController to the Subscriber. During screensharing, Subscriber should be able to see full screen of Publisher. But Subscriber is able to see  Publisher's screen in the second half of the screen, in the first half Subcriber's video is there. How can we remove Subscriber's video during screen sharing? when we stop screen sharing, Subscriber's video should come again.

Comment: Can you mark this as the answer so I can use it to mark a duplicate question as answered please. The videos on the stream are normal `UIView`s you can store them as  properties on your view controller and show/hide as you wish: 

https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo/blob/43853a998f0ca378ac75137118778b2a38fd2333/Basic-Video-Chat/ViewController.swift#L233 

https://github.com/abdulajet/opentok-screenshare-demo/blob/43853a998f0ca378ac75137118778b2a38fd2333/Basic-Video-Chat/ViewController.swift#L104