# How to stop ScreenSharing manually with tokbox sdk in Swift

Tags: swift, opentok, tokbox

I am working on an IOS application(SWIFT) in which i have used tokbox sdk for screensharing during video call, i am able to share the screen but not able to stop screensharing.
This is the code I have used for screensharing.

```
publisher?.videoType = .screen
publisher?.audioFallbackEnabled = false
let capturer = ScreenCapturer(withView:view)
publisher?.videoCapture = capturer
session?.publish(publisher, error: &error)
```

To stop screensharing i have used the following code!

```
let capturer = ScreenCapturer(withView:view)
publisher?.videoCapture = capturer
capturer.stop()
publisher?.videoType = .camera
publisher?.audioFallbackEnabled = false
publisher?.publishVideo = true
```

Can anyone tell what is the process for stoping the screensharing once we click on stop button and we should be able to continue video call ?

Comment: check out this other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64550310/how-to-stop-tokbox-screen-sharing-in-swift

Comment: Hai! yes its working thank you for sharing the thread!
i have one more question can u answer that ?
my Question is will opentok works for tvOS ?
our project goal is screen mirroring the session to apple TV. (from mobile to tvOS )!
i tried to install pod OpenTok in tvOS app but im getting the error! The error is [!] The platform of the target `OpenTokSample` (tvOS 14.0) is not compatible with `OpenTok (2.18.1)`, which does not support `tvOS`.

Comment: The SDK does not have specific builds for tvOS. You can try using the JS SDK in a tvOS webview?

Comment: Hai! Thank you for your suggestion but There is No webview in tvOS.Apple has deleted several iOS frameworks, making tvOS unique (most notably WebKit). Can You suggest any other alternative ?

Comment: can i see source code of opentok ?

Comment: Our library is closed source, so we cannot share that with you